# I want to insert function call if date match with my session date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my current session, I have two dates `$start_date` and `$end_date` and current date which is present in

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$now = date('Y-m-d');
```

In `$now` have todays date and I compare today's date with `$start_date` and `$end_date`    if the condition  true then I want to call my insert function

```
$modelResult = $this->biltyModel->insertBilty($data);
```

Following is my code

```
public function insertRecord(){

    $name           = $this->input->post('name');
    $number     = $this->input->post('number');

    $formData=array();
    $data = array(
            'name'        =>$name,
            'number'      =>$number,
        );

    $start_date = $this->session->userdata('start_date');
    $end_date   = $this->session->userdata('end_date');

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $now = date('Y-m-d');

    if ($now >= $start_date && $now <= $end_date) {
        $modelResult = $this->biltyModel->insertBilty($data);
    }else{
        $formData['create_bilty'] = array(
                'form_status'       => 'false',
                'form_message'      => 'Not in current Session'
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($formData);
}
```

In this code, it goves in only else part.

```
 $start_date = 2019-04-01 
 $end_date   = 2020-03-31
 $now = 2019-09-05
```

Comment: Strange, that code works here

Comment: Can you show us a `var_dump($start_date);` and `var_dump($end_date);` and `var_dump($now);` please

Comment: @RiggsFolly I use ` if (strtotime($now) >= strtotime($start_date) && strtotime($now) <= strtotime($end_date)){` this code and its working

Comment: You need to convert date string ( $start_date, $end_date and $now ) to a particular format, try to use strtotime() for all 4 dates.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the dates into timestamp

```
$start_time = strtotime($start_date);
$end_time = strtotime($end_date);
$now = time();

if( $now >= $start_time && $now <= $end_time ){
      /* your code  */
}
```